# How do I use the Public Activity gem in Rails 4 to notify every user involved in a post's comment thread?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

My app has posts which have comments. This is the functionality I would like: A user sees the comment activity on the post he has created AND a commenter sees comment activity on the posts he has commented on.

My models:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :user
belongs_to :course
has_many :comments, dependent: :destroy
end


class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
include PublicActivity::Model
tracked except: :update, owner: ->(controller, model) { controller && controller.current_user }

belongs_to :post
belongs_to :user

end
```

And the Activities controller:

```
class ActivitiesController < ApplicationController
def index
@activities = PublicActivity::Activity.order("created_at desc")

end
end
```

And the Activities index view:

```
<% @activities.each do |activity| %>
<div class="activity">
<%= link_to activity.owner.username, activity.owner if activity.owner %>

added comment to <%= link_to activity.trackable.post.title, activity.trackable.post %>
 </div>
 <% end %>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid the PublicActivity gem is not designed to do this. It is meant to create one activity when one activity happens. In your case you need to create possible many notification records (1/user) if an activity happens. We had the same problem at my work and we decided to create a Notification model that is similar to the PublicActivity implementation.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :notifications, foreign_key: :notified_user_id, dependent: :destroy
end

class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  # maybe it would be better to name it as inverse_notifications
  has_many :notifications, as: :trackable, dependent: :destroy
end

class Notification < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :trackable, polymorphic: true
  belongs_to :acting_user, class_name: "User"
  belongs_to :notified_user, class_name: "User"

  validates_presence_of :trackable, :notified_user, :key

  scope :unread, -> { where("read_at IS NULL") }
end
```

This allows you to create 2 types of notifications when a comment is created:

- one for the owner with `key: "post.commented"`
- many for the commenters with `key: "comment.created"`

And it is possible to set the `read_at` attribute if the user has seen it, so you can add different style to them on the frontend.